Computing camera attitude so points along/follows spline
Assuming I have a spline that I want a camera to follow, is there a simple way to compute the orientation of the camera such that its optical center aligns with the vector defining the derivative of the spline?
In other words I want the camera to be oriented so the spline goes through the center of the image created.
I am using axis angle orientation for attitude but I can convert to any.
I'm not using an engine, I just need the mathematical details.

The exact steps depend on your spline type (if you need help computing the derivative), your tech stack (so we know what transformation API you have to orient your camera — e.g. do you need a quaternion, Tait-Bryan angles, etc.) and how your coordinate system is set up. Can you edit your question to clarify these details?

I tried to add some.

So, your question reduces to: "How can I compute an axis-angle rotation that transforms  direction A to direction B?" where A is your camera's viewing axis, and B is the spline's derivative?

I think so, but rotation about the axis is undefined so is to be kept constant.

Maintaining a constant orientation about the viewing axis is unfortunately not something we can guarantee - the Hairy Ball Theorem strikes again - see this past Q&A for more on that.
For a camera, what we usually want is that our local "up" vector should remain continuous frame to frame (no big jumps / discontinuities), and when the spline is not too steep, we should gradually rotate to get that up vector as close to the world up direction as we can.
Here's a procedure we can use for that:
Vector3 viewDirection = spline.GetUnitTangentAt(progress);

Vector3 targetUp = previousUp + worldUp * untwistRate * deltaTime;

// Ensure localUp is perpendicular to viewDirection and of unit length
Vector3 localUp = Normalize(targetUp - Dot(viewDirection, targetUp) * viewDirection);

From these two basis vectors, we can construct a 3x3 rotation matrix, and either use that directly (if your code allows for it) or extract an angle-axis form from it.
The remaining steps depend on your coordinate system, which you haven't specified, so I'll use a common left-handed convention of {x+ = right, y+ = up, z+ = forward}
Our rotation matrix would then look like, this, where our localUp and viewDirection (forward) vectors form the second and third columns, and the first column is their cross product.
$$R = \begin{bmatrix} \left(\vec u \times \vec f \right) & \vec u & \vec f \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
u_y f_z - u_z f_y & u_x & f_x \\ 
u_z f_x - u_x f_z & u_y & f_y \\
u_x f_y - u_y f_x & u_z & f_z  
\end{bmatrix}$$
As shown on Wikipedia here, we can compute the rotation angle using the trace of this matrix:
$$\begin{align}
\theta &= \cos^{-1} \frac {\text {tr}(R) - 1} 2\\
&=  \cos^{-1} \frac {u_yf_z - u_zf_y + u_y + f_z - 1} 2\\ 
\end{align}$$
If that comes out to zero, the object is still in its default orientation, and you can pick a rotation axis arbitrarily (rotating 0° around any axis gives the same result).
If it comes out less than 180°, we can extract the axis \$\vec a\$ like so:
$$\vec a = \begin{bmatrix} R_{32} - R_{23} \\ R_{13} - R_{31} \\ R_{21} - R_{12} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}u_z - f_y \\ f_x - u_xf_y + u_yf_x  \\ u_zf_x - u_xf_z - u_x\end{bmatrix}$$
For exactly 180° rotations, this will give us a zero vector, and for rotations close to that, we may lose numeric stability. As Wikipedia states:

In this case, it is necessary to diagonalize R and find the eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue of 1.

You can use that eigenvector as your rotation axis. I'm a little rusty on eigenvectors (I usually work with rotations as quaternions or matrices, rather than angle-axis form), so the last few steps for this case are left as an exercise for the reader. 
